# find and replace a unique html (href) string using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, replace

Using Javascript, how can I change this classless anchor (assuming targeting unique href string):

```
<a href="/unique-url-string/"></a>
```

to this, on page load:

```
<a href="/replacement-url-string/"></a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select the element based on its `href` prop.

```
$('a[href="/unique-url-string/"]').prop('href', '/replacement-url-string/');
```

If you want to only search the `pathname` of these urls and keep the domain name the same you can try something like:

```
$('a').filter(function() {
  return this.pathname === "/foo/bar"
}).prop('href', function () {
  this.pathname = '/butt/butt/butt';
  return this;
});
```

Comment: fantastic! did it. out of curiosity, would it be as easy to replace say only a portion of the href string? for example: domain.com/unique-string/ to domain.com/replacement-url-string/ but ignoring the domain.com portion?

Comment: You'd have to keep track of what the domain is since you'd be rewriting the whole thing.  I'll post a small update to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using only JavaScript without library

```
function replaceLink(oldLink, newLink) {
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        if(x[i].href == oldLink) {
            x[i].href == newLink; 
            break; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
   $('a[href="/unique-url-string/"]').attr('href', '/replacement-url-string/'); 
});
```

To replace a portion:

```
$(function(){
    var a = $('a[href="/unique-url-string/"]');
   a.attr('href', a.attr('href').replace('unique', 'replacement')); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this :

```
$().ready(function(){
    $('a').attr("href").replace("unique","replacement");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var link = document.getElementById('linkToChange');
console.log(link.href);
link.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

```html
<a href="about:blank" id="linkToChange">me</a>
```